# How to verify a certificate using .cer file in Java

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, x509certificate, public-key-encryption

I'm trying to verify a certificate , that was given to me using Java, in the following manner

```
        try{
        FileInputStream fr = new FileInputStream(pathtoCertificate);
        CertificateFactory cf =   CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509");
        X509Certificate c = (X509Certificate) 
                            cf.generateCertificate(fr);
        System.out.println("++++Certificate Verification++++++++");
        PublicKey pk = c.getPublicKey();
        c.verify(pk);....//63
System.out.println("++This certificate is VALID++");
    .....

    }
    catch(CertificateException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Certificate is Invalid");
            }
```

However, I keep getting the following error

```
java.security.SignatureException: Signature does not match.
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.verify(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.verify(Unknown Source)
    at Main.printCertificate(Main.java:63)
    at Main.main(Main.java:41)
```

I've only been provided with a certificate file(which I need to verify), a private key(corresponding to the above file ) and a certificate from a CA.
I'm quite new to Java Security. So any thoughts on how I could verify the certificate file would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I finally figured it out. For folks who may reach here in the future.
The reason the error was being thrown is that the certificate in my case was not `self signed` . Therefore I merely had to use the certificate issued by the CA(as mentioned in my Q) to verify the public key.
The rest remained the same.